# Google application script - using setInterval in in onOpen trigger - error "undefined"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am trying to use setInterval function in onOpen trigger. When I run it I am getting " "setInterval" is not defined." error. Are there any restrictions to using setInterval in Google Application Script?

This is the code:

```
setInterval(function(){
  Logger.log("test");
}, 100);
```

Comment: SetInterval is not part of javascript. Its a browser function and onOpen runs on server not browser.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use Time triggers
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_time_triggers