# setInterval is not defined

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I have a project in google sheets, and every 5 minutes I would like a function to run that scrolls down to the last row that contains text. I have a function that works fine, however, I can't get the setInterval to work; I keep getting the reference error "setInterval is not defined."

```
function autoScroll() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
    v = s.getRange('A:A').getValues(),
    l = v.length,
    r = 1;
while (l > 0) {
    if (v[l] && v[l][0].toString().length > 0) {
        r = (l + 2);
        break;
    } else {
        l--;
    }
}
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveRange(s.getRange(r, 1));

}

setInterval (autoScroll, 300,000);
```

Comment: Not the problem, but you need to remove the comma from `300,000`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388143/google-application-script-using-setinterval-in-in-onopen-trigger-error-unde